# How to ask libcurl not to listen on a socket just send a url request over it?

Tags: sockets, libcurl, asyncsocket, libevent

I have a client that manages the socket connection on its own (actually using `libevent`'s `bufferevent`). Now, I'd like to use `libcurl` to produce and send HTML `GET` requests on that socket. I'm done with this part by feeding `libcurl`, my already opened socket using `OPENSOCKET_FUNCTION` option.

But my problem is now that both `libevent` and `libcurl` are listening on the socket and sometimes it's `libevent` who answers to the socket when it has data, and sometimes it's `libcurl`.

Is there way to tell libcurl to just produce and send the `GET` request for the url, but not to listen on socket so I can take the matters in my hand after `libcurl` wrote the url in the socket?

Obviously, I'm using `curl_mult`i interface for non-blocking sockets, otherwise `curl_easy_perform` doesn't return 'til it receives its answer.

I don't want to let the `bufferevent` listener go and stay with `libcurl`, because it's a multi-protocol program, and I'm implementing the http part of it. Other protocols don't have the luxury of using `libcurl`, so I need to keep the `bufferevent` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [curl_multi_socket_action()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html) function. An example use of that function together with libevent is provided by curl in the [hiperfifo.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/hiperfifo.html) source.

Comment: I did the following:
1. Only activated EV_WRITE in creation of event:
"event* write_url_event = event_new(the_event, the_socket, EV_WRITE, curl_socket_event_cb, arg);"
2. Disabled libevent write callback:
"bufferevent_disable(conn->buffer, EV_WRITE);"
3. And when the event call back gets called, I called curl_multi_socket_action() only with CURL_CSELECT_OUT:
"rc = curl_multi_socket_action(curl_multi_handle, fd, CURL_CSELECT_OUT, &curl_running_handle);"
Still I'm losing some packets that are sent by the peer on the socket. I never receive them on otherside. Could it be a bug with libcurl?

Comment: This is not a libcurl forum, ask detailed questions on the libcurl list. It could be a bug in the lib, could be a bug in your app. Or both. The general method is still as I have described and which is documented.

Comment: Sorry for flip floping on the acceptance. It actually worked perfectly. The problem was that the terminal that I was using was not honest in printing out all of stderr and as such, I thought I'm losing packets.